# How to copy between guest OS (Windows 7) running inside Oracle virtual machine 5.0 to host OS (CentOS Release 4.0 final)

Tags: linux, centos, virtual-host

Need help to resolve copy and paste bidirectional from guest OS (Windows 7) and host OS (*CentOS Release 4.0 final*) or from host OS to guest OS

I applied tick mark to bidirectional Drag-n-Drop and Shared Clipboard under Setting → General → Advance tab

Thanks for any help and suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the [VirtualBox Guest Additions](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) on the guest.

You can do that by choosing `Devices` and the `Insert Guest Additions`.

If that does not work you can download them [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads).

You need to reboot the guest and then it should work.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I am unable to locate Device menu at my Windows 7 OS which running inside Oracle VM VirtualBox

Comment: There should be a menu called "Devices" or something similar in the VirtualBox window in the menu bar. It's the menu where you find "Drag and Drop" and "Bidirectional clipboard". I don't have the English version installed but I am sure you will find what I mean.